# when the validity of an input depends on the value of another input - or how to trigger validation in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, validation

As demonstrative in the following code sample, the input named amountOrPercet can be interpreted as an amount or as a percentage value, depending on the state of the mode radio button.

```
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="amt" ng-model="mode"/> Amount
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="pct"ng-model="mode"/> Percent

<input type="text" name="amountOrPercent" ng-model="amountOrPercent" check-percent/>
```

I have put together an attribute directive to invalidate amountOrPercent for values greater than 100, in case it must be interpreted as a percentage:

```
myApp.directive('checkPct', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {

        ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
            var valid = scope.mode != 'pct' || value <= 100;
            ngModel.$setValidity('checkPct', valid);
            return valid ? value : undefined;
        });

        ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
            ngModel.$setValidity('checkPct', scope.mode != 'pct' || value <= 100);
            return value;
        });
    }
};
```

});

When the value of mode it kept unchanged, The validation works as expected. However when the value of mode is changed, the value of amountOrPercent is not re-validated, unless user changes the value of amountOrPercentage. 
I know that I can use a watch to do some action based on changes in mode, but my question is how I can trigger the validation on amountOrPercent, when mode is changed. - Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add watcher for `mode` and revalidate value when it changes:

```
scope.$watch('mode', function(){
  var valid = scope.mode != 'pct' || ngModel.$modelValue <= 100;
  ngModel.$setValidity('checkPct', valid);

}
```